# When i try to send embed message it gives error

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

U can see my problem in the full error pls help me.

Im making a bot to sell cuz i can have money with it.

**CODE**

```js
        const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
        const helpchannel = msg.channel
        const helpEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    
            .setColor('#ffffff')
            .setTitle('COMMANDS HELP')
            .setAuthor('poemo224', 'https://i.imgur.com/oK6epiz.jpg')
            .setDescription('All Bot Commands')
            .setThumbnail(`${msg.guild.icon}`)
            .addFields(
                { name: `${msg.guild.name} INVITE`, value: `INVITE` },
                { name: 'BAN', value: 'Bans defined user.'},
                { name: 'KICK', value: 'Kicks defined user.'},
                { name: 'INFO', value: 'Info about Lyxon Bot.'},
                { name: 'HELP', value: 'Shows all commands with an embed message.'},
                { name: 'RULES', value: 'Shows rules with an embed message.'},
                { name: 'CLEAR', value: 'Deletes message as user defined.'},
                { name: 'CREDITS', value: 'Shows credits on Lyxon Bot.'},
                { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
                { name: 'Prefix', value: '$', inline: true },
                { name: 'Clear Count', value: 'Max clear count is 100', inline: true },
            )
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter('by poemo224');
    
        helpchannel.send({ embeds: [helpEmbed] });
```

**FULL ERROR**

```js
C:\Users\Mustikk\Desktop\Projects\Lxyon\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embeds[0].thumbnail.url: Scheme "ebdc8375674885bc32bdf9c8d9415d53" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ('http', 'https').
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Mustikk\Desktop\Projects\Lxyon\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Mustikk\Desktop\Projects\Lxyon\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (C:\Users\Mustikk\Desktop\Projects\Lxyon\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:171:15) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/877463391256596481/messages',
  code: 50035,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: [
        {
          title: 'COMMANDS HELP',
          type: 'rich',
          description: 'All Bot Commands',
          url: null,
          timestamp: 2021-08-19T18:11:27.753Z,
          color: 16777215,
          fields: [
            [Object], [Object],
            [Object], [Object],
            [Object], [Object],
            [Object], [Object],
            [Object], [Object],
            [Object]
          ],
          thumbnail: {
            url: 'ebdc8375674885bc32bdf9c8d9415d53',
            proxyURL: undefined,
            height: undefined,
            width: undefined
          },
          image: null,
          author: {
            name: 'poemo224',
            url: undefined,
            icon_url: 'https://i.imgur.com/oK6epiz.jpg'
          },
          footer: { text: 'by poemo224', icon_url: undefined }
        }
      ],
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

Comment: The "your post is mostly code", is there for a reason.

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MessageEmbed.setThumbnail()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setThumbnail) accepts a URL as its parameter. You are currently using [`Guild.icon`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Guild?scrollTo=icon) which returns the hash of the guild icon. Instead you may want to use the [`Guild.iconURL()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Guild?scrollTo=iconURL) method.

```js
setThumbnail(msg.guild.iconURL())
```

<sub>Note: I took out the `MessageEmbed().setColor().setTitle()` etc to save space</sub>